# Django Rest API's sub routes are not accessible on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, google-app-engine, django-rest-framework, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Rest API developed with Django Rest Framework. It is completely functional  when running locally with:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

All requests work as expected:

> 127.0.0.1:8000/

[image: http://127.0.0.1:8000/]

> 127.0.0.1:8000/projects/

[image: http://127.0.0.1:8000/projects]

Now the issues arise when deploying from a cloud service such as AWS Elastic Beanstalk or Google App Engine. The defaut route works fine as shown below. The projects route however does not load. The request code received varys by platform. App Engine give a `502 Bad Gateway` code and Beanstalk gives a `504 Gateway Timeout`. With Beanstalk, running `eb logs` reveal no errors.

> projects-restapi-dev.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/

[image: projects-restapi-dev.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/]

> projects-restapi-dev.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/projects

[image]

I'm certain the issue has something to do with how i'm routing my views. Here's my urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import path, include
from projects.views import ProjectView
from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'projects', ProjectView)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path("projects/", ProjectView),
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("api-auth/", include('rest_framework.urls'))
]
```

Also, [here's](https://github.com/malik-tillman/AWS-Django-Rest-API) a link to the github repo if you need to see any other files.

Comment: Is your database ip and port publicly accessible? Because if ELB is retruning 504 timeout, means your app is trying to connect database and it is not able to connect.

Comment: i checked your database host ip `35.196.52.118` , which doesn't have postgres port 5432 open to public access.

Comment: Also, a advise for you, don't put database creds and other secrets openly in public git projects. Use environment variables for managing them.

Comment: So why does it work when I deploy Django from the dev server? That IP is not a local one (it's hosted by Google SQL).

Comment: Also, I know about the environment variable thing. I've been getting around to that but that isn't anything secret at the moment. Nothing is finalized and I'm only testing services.

Comment: Are you following any tutorials for deploying onto App Engine? If so, can you share it here?

Comment: I've been following [this one](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/flexible-environment) by Google. I think the problem is with how I went about accessing the database. Google SQL requires a list of IPs that must be granted access to be able to connect. At the time of using GAE, I believe the fix was as easy as enabling private IP, granting access for my GAE instances. I don't think it's that simple of a fix for AWS, Haruko, or any other PaaS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue happens because the Django app is attempting to access a database from an IP which has not been granted access. When running on your local server the database recognizes a white-listed IP and allows access. When running from a PaaS (like AWS, App Engine, or Python Anywhere) you are likely accessing your database from a range of possible IPs.

The simple fix for someone hosting SQL with Google and using App Engine:

> Enable `Private IP` in your connection tab of the SQL instance.

This enables you to connect to an SQL instance from another app running on Google's cloud service.

If you are hosting SQL with Google and deploying your app on another PaaS, the solution is more involve. Solutions vary by platform, so some addition research is required by case.